# rake db:sessions:create fail cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a new rails 4.0.0 app I run rake db:sessions:create and get the following error:

```
rake db:sessions:create
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rails/generators/rails/session_migration/session_migration_generator
```

rake db:create works fine.

Gemfile

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'
```

.config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Answer (score 3):

rails generate active_record:session_migration

Comment: I did what you say, but then ´rake db:migrate´ ... Is not what I would prefer because I had this issue with development database, after recreate it from Oracle server (because I needed new data) . So now I have a migrattion pending in production. Now I have to remove this migration from source and shema_migrations table